# Using a loop with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hi I have a module which uses the value of a ComboBox to determine Which Column ARRAY should be applied when copying information from One WS to a significant number of text boxes on a User Form.
There are 8 possible values for the ComboxBox each pulls informarion from a different ARRAY. The row range is the same for all 8 ComboBox Values.
I currently have 8 similar sets of Code in the module and am looking for a way to maybe use a series of IF / ELSEIF statements and create a single instance of the Loop Code.

Example Code (Partial - DIm and other lines are omitted for this example)

```
If cbo1.Value = "Draw 1" Then
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
     tbCounter = 1
    vCols = Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
    For lngRowLoop = 44 To 56
        For lngCtrlLoop = 0 To UBound(vCols)
        Me.Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = 
        ws.Range(vCols(lngCtrlLoop) & lngRowLoop).Value
        tbCounter = tbCounter + 1
       Next
    Next
    If cbo1.Value = "Draw 2" Then
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
     tbCounter = 1
    vCols = Array("H", "I", "L", "K", "L", "M")
    For lngRowLoop = 44 To 56
        For lngCtrlLoop = 0 To UBound(vCols)
        Me.Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = 
        ws.Range(vCols(lngCtrlLoop) & lngRowLoop).Value
        tbCounter = tbCounter + 1
       Next
    Next
```

Is there a solution that will allow for all 8 sets of the variable information to be placed before the Loop Code?

Comment: That's why VBA has the ability to create subs and functions..

Comment: I would put 8 sets of `If .. then` and `End If` - you need your `End If`s as your code is ambiguous as it is.

Comment: Welcome Denny57! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Are we talking about 78 text boxes?

Comment: Yes also I have tried the If ...Then optoin but this will not run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `Dictionary` object

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim cbToColsDict As Object
        Set cbToColsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
            With cbToColsDict
                .Add "Draw 1", Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
                .Add "Draw 2", Array("H", "I", "L", "K", "L", "M")
                '...
            End With

        With Me
        
            Dim vCols As Variant
                vCols = cbToColsDict(.cb01.Value)
                
            Set ws = Worksheet("Sheet1")
            
            Dim tbCounter As Long
                tbCounter = 1
                
                Dim lngRowLoop As Long
                    For lngRowLoop = 44 To 56
                    
                        Dim vCol As Variant
                            For Each vCol In vCols
                                .Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = ws.Cells(lngRowLoop, vCol).Value
                                tbCounter = tbCounter + 1
                            Next
                       
                    Next
                
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you  This works perfectly well. I wil need to work out how to do this in reverse, That is to populate the Ws with values from the TextBoxes.  I will try this tomorrow

Comment: You’re welcome. You may then want to mark the solution as accepted and help future readers of this thread

Comment: Hi I would like to extend this code under the same command button to apply similar code to two other sets of data. They are both depenant on the value of cbo1 and have a row range of 46 To 58 but apply the results to a single Row and different textboxes. The source wsheet is also different for each additional piece of code. l s this possible within the one command? I have tried to adapt the code but it keeps returning errors.

Comment: @Denny57, you'd better make a new post to both follow this site rules and have more chance to get a faster solution. In the new post, take care to give all needed information

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starter for 10

```
Option Explicit

' This type definition goes in your class/form module
Private Type State
    
    vcols               As Collection
    tbcounter           As Long

End Type


Private s               As State


' call this method to set up your arrays
Public Sub PopulateVCols()

    Set s.vcols = New Collection
    With s.vcols
    
        .Add Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
        .Add Array("H", "I", "L", "K", "L", "M")
        ' etc
        
    End With
    
End Sub


' Takes an integer starting at 1 to select the vcol array and Sheet
Public Sub DoTheStuffThatNeedsDoing(ByVal ipSelector As Long)
    Set myWs = Sheets("Sheet" & CStr(ipSelector))
    s.tbcounter = 1
    
    For lngRowLoop = 44 To 56
        For lngCtrlLoop = 0 To UBound(vcols.Item(ipSelector))
        Me.Controls("txtBox" & s.tbCounter).Text =
        ws.Range(s.vcols.item(ipselector)) & lngRowLoop).Value
        s.tbcounter = s.tbcounter + 1
       Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried to amend this code with the required information relenat to the user form. The Add.Array is not accecpted (= expected message) . There appears to be an erroneous ) after lngRowLoop and I am slightly confused by the Option Explicit "Private s as State as this seems ro be outside ant Sub parameters. Additionally, there does not appear to be any code to look up the information in the cbo to determine which array should be used. I am a novice to VBA but can usually work out what the code is doing, but this seems to be missing some elements

Answer (score 0):

### Populate Multiple Text Boxes

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub PopulateTextBoxesQF()
    
    Dim Cols(): Cols = VBA.Array( _
        VBA.Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), _
        VBA.Array("H", "I", "L", "K", "L", "M"))

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim dString As String: dString = cob1.Value
    Dim dPos As Long: dPos = InStrRev(dString, " ") + 1
    Dim dIndex As Long: dIndex = Mid(dString, dPos, Len(dString) - dPos) - 1
    
    Dim dCols(): dCols = Cols(dIndex)
    Dim dUB As Long: dUB = UBound(dCols)
 
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, tbCounter As Long
   
    For r = 44 To 56
        For c = 0 To dUB
            tbCounter = tbCounter + 1
            Me.Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = ws.Cells(r, dCols(c)).Value
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

```vb
Sub PopulateTextBoxes()
    
    Dim Cols(): Cols = VBA.Array( _
        VBA.Array("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), _
        VBA.Array("H", "I", "L", "K", "L", "M"))

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = ws.Rows("44:56")
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rrg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim dString As String: dString = cob1.Value
    Dim dPos As Long: dPos = InStrRev(dString, " ") + 1
    Dim dIndex As Long: dIndex = Mid(dString, dPos, Len(dString) - dPos) - 1
    
    Dim dCols(): dCols = Cols(dIndex)
    Dim dUB As Long: dUB = UBound(dCols)
 
    Dim Data(), r As Long, c As Long, tbCounter As Long
   
    For c = 0 To dUB
        Data = rrg.Columns(dCols(c)).Value
        tbCounter = c + 1
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Me.Controls("txtBox" & tbCounter).Text = Data(r, 1)
            tbCounter = tbCounter + dUB + 1
        Next r
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a duplicate Decalration in Current Scope at the first instance of dIndexDim dIndex As Long: dIndex = Mid(dString, dPos, Len(dString) - dPos) - 1
    
    Dim dCols(): dCols = Cols(dIndex)

Comment: That would mean that I have declared `dIndex` or `dCols` twice. But I can't find the second declaration.

Comment: I now get a message Type Mismatch on the same line

Comment: There are 2 variables for dCols  Dim Cols(): Cols = VBA.Array( _ & Dim dCols(): dCols = Cols(dIndex)

Comment: Hoowever the code fails on a line without dCols.  I have tried to add extra lines of Array but VBA does not accept them, any reason for this